# Pull a column from sqlite3 and use those data in django dropdown

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, drop-down-menu

----models.py----
This model uses sqlite3 default database of django

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class item_master(models.Model):
    item_name=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=False)
    item_price=models.IntegerField(max_length=5,null=False)
```

---

----views.py----
These are many pages in this django app... "abc.html" is the page which needs drop-down list and "showitems" is the related function.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django import template
from app.models import item_master
from django import forms
from django_select2.forms import ModelSelect2Widget
from django.views import generic
import sqlite3

@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def index(request):

    context = {}
    context['segment'] = 'index'

    html_template = loader.get_template( 'index.html' )
    return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))

@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def pages(request):
    context = {}

    try:

        load_template      = request.path.split('/')[-1]
        print(load_template)
        context['segment'] = load_template
        html_template = loader.get_template( load_template )
        if (load_template == "test.html"):
            items(request)
            return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))
        elif (load_template == "abc.html"):
            showitems(request)
            return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))
        else:
            return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))

    except template.TemplateDoesNotExist:

        html_template = loader.get_template( 'page-404.html' )
        return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))

    except:

        html_template = loader.get_template( 'page-500.html' )
        return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))

def showitems(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        showdrop = item_master.objects.all()
        return render(request,'abc.html',{"showdrop":showdrop})
```

----abc.html----
HTML code for the front end

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.min.js" integrity="sha256-+C0A5Ilqmu4QcSPxrlGpaZxJ04VjsRjKu+G82kl5UJk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.bootstrap3.min.css" integrity="sha256-ze/OEYGcFbPRmvCnrSeKbRTtjG4vGLHXgOqsyLFTRjg=" crossorigin="anonymous" />


<select  id="selectitem" class="form-control" >
<option selected disabled="True">--- select --- </option>
  {% for result in showdrop %}
  <option value="{{result.id}}">{{result.item_name}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

[Dropdown is not listing any item][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8l0G.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `abc.html` seems correct. Your `showitems` function is passing all of that information correctly as well based on what you have there.

Maybe it's how you have used the `showitems` function... Where you have called it at

```
elif (load_template == "abc.html"):
    showitems(request)
    return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))
```

After the `showitems` function have been used to render the information on the `abc.html` page, it will then come back and run this line `return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))` which is most likely overrriding what the `showitems` function have place in the `abc.html` page.

I understand that you want to validate the pages so you can display the error pages such as `page-404.html` and `page-500.html`. My suggestion to you is to have your `showitems` function to return the list of objects for `item_master` and not to try and render any information from there to the `abc.html`.

For example:

In your `pages` function...

```
elif (load_template == "abc.html"):
    context['showdrop'] = showitems(request) # Having the showdrop returned here to pass within this context.
    return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))
```

In your showitems function...

```
def showitems(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        showdrop = item_master.objects.all()
        return showdrop
```

This should be fine if you have not declared `showitems` as an independent view within your `urls.py`.

OR...

You can comment out `return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))`

```
elif (load_template == "abc.html"):
    showitems(request)
    # return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))
```

And have your showitems function to do the work by rendering the details from there...

```
def showitems(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        showdrop = item_master.objects.all()
        return render(request,'abc.html',{"showdrop":showdrop})
```

Comment: @Mio Myazz How to get search box for this drop-down list. In all the contents out there, suggests to use django-select2. Is there any other way to get it done?

Comment: @harishkrishna I'm not familiar with the `django-select2` package. I've done a bit of reading just now and it seems like you would have some additional edits to do to your code to get this done. Maybe `jQuery` can be used to get this done as well, but I'm sure you can write a view to handle the search box form that will validate whether if an item exist for the value entered in the search box.

Comment: @Mio Myazz I tried to add select2 and finally i made it!

Comment: Congrats my bro! I'll be giving that package a try soon.